# Lehmer's totient problem generalization (adding a constant )

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, totient-function

[Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) is an well-known open problem which states that the divisibility :

> $$\phi(n) \mid n-1$$ holds only for primes .

This motivated me to ask the following :

> For which integers $k$ we can find a **composite** $n$ such that $$\phi(n)+k \mid n-1+k$$

Obviously we can reduce the divisibility to $$\phi(n)+k \mid n-1-\phi(n)$$
For example trying with some composites :

- $n=4$ gives $2+k \mid 1$ which leads to $k=-1$ and $k=-3$
- $n=6$ gives $2+k \mid 3$ which leads to $k=1,-1,-3,-5$
- $n=9$ gives $6+k \mid 2$ which leads to $k=-4,-5,-7,-8$

There seems to be a lot of values that work .I am pretty confident that all the values except $0$ will appear at some point :

> **Conjecture** 
>   All $k$'s except $0$ have this property .

This seems true but I'm completely stuck on how to prove such a thing .

I would love to see a proof of this fact (if it's even true ) .

Thanks a lot for your time to help me with this .I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I tried to code a program, $k=6, 10, 12, 18$ are not appearing yet, by testing $n$ up to $10^5$.

Comment: I increased it to 10^6, and those numbers are not appearing yet too. Other notable possible counterexamples include $-12, -72$.

Comment: Wow this is nice thanks a lot . It seems that all possible counter-examples are even (like $0$ which is also probably a counter-example ) . I would be very nice if someone can prove that all odd numbers work .

Comment: It is quite easy to show that all negative odd numbers work, by setting $k=-n+1$.

Comment: Didn't thought of making $n-k+1=0$ :) . So this means that $-n+1$ with $n$ composite works .

Comment: Is there any reason why $\phi(n)+k \mid n-1+k$ is a better more interesting version than any of the following $\phi(n)+k \mid n-1-k$, $\phi(n)-k \mid n-1+k$, $\phi(n)-k \mid n-1-k$, $\phi(n)+k \mid (n-1)k$, how would one come up with a natural or a best version of a problem formulated as a variation of $\phi(n) \mid n-1$. Why exactly $\phi(n)+k \mid n-1+k$? Why is the conjecture that all $k$ except $0$ have this property, why not conjecture that all $k$ have this property?

Comment: It's obvious that starting from $$ \phi(n) \mid n-1$$ you can make a lot (an infinite number ) of possible generalizations , many of whom would surely be open problems . I don't have a good explanation why this problem is more interesting than the others , it's just that this is the problem I thought of as a generalization